# A challenging problem on continuity-MADHAVA-2020.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity, problem-solving

Suppose $f$ be a continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $f(\frac{x}{x+1})=f(x)+2$.Is the function monotonically decreasing?I have tried to prove it in different ways but still I could not find any way out.Also how to show $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0+$.Actually it is a question from MADHAVA-2020 which took place on 12 Jan,2020.

Comment: First thoughts: We know that $f(\frac{x}{x+1}) > f(x)$. If we **assume** that $f$ is monotone and decreasing, where does that lead us?

Comment: @MattiP. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Tell us that MADHAVA 2020 is an exam that took place this past Sunday, so that we can tell it is now finished.  http://madhavacompetition.com

Comment: @GEdgar what do you mean?Madhava is over past sunday.

Comment: I mean: you should say that in your question, so that we will know it is over.

Comment: If one shows that $f$ is monotone ally decreasing then it can be easily shown that limit of $f(x) $ as $x\to 0^{+}$ is $\infty $. The first part about monotone behavior seems tricky.

Comment: The limit is easy to show regardless from iterating the map $x\mapsto x/(x+1)$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri How please write an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x):={2\over x}+\sin{2\pi\over x}\qquad(0<x<\infty)\ .$$
Then
$$f\left({x\over x+1}\right)={2(x+1)\over x}+\sin{2\pi(x+1)\over x}=f(x)+2\qquad(0<x<\infty)\ .$$
Furthermore
$$f'(x)=-{2\over x^2}-{2\pi\over x^2}\cos{2\pi\over x}=-{2\over x^2}\left(1+\pi \cos{2\pi\over x}\right)\ .$$
Here the RHS is positive on the intervals where $\cos{2\pi\over x}<-{1\over\pi}$; hence $f$ is not decreasing in these intervals.

In order to find the general solution to the given functional equation we replace the variable $x$ by $x:={1\over u}$ $\>(0<u<\infty)$. This means that instead of $f$ we now look at the function
$$g(u):=f\left({1\over u}\right)\ .\tag{1}$$
We now have
$$g(u+1)=f\left({1\over u+1}\right)=f\left({{1\over u}\over {1\over u}+1}\right)=f\left({1\over u}\right)+2=g(u)+2\ .$$
This implies that
$$g(u)=2u+h(u)\ ,$$
where $h$ is periodic with period $1$. From $(1)$ we then get
$$f(x)=g\left({1\over x}\right)={2\over x}+h\left({1\over x}\right)\ .$$
If $f$ is continuous then $h$ has to be continuous as well, hence the periodic $h$ is bounded. This implies $\lim_{x\to0+} f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: How to show that the limit at 0+ is infinity?

Comment: Brilliant new edit! +1

Answer (score 3):

I am led to believe that the answer is no.

Let $g:(0,+\infty) \longrightarrow (0,1)$ be given by $g(x) = x/(x+1)$.
The statement of the problem gives us that $f(g(x)) = f(x) + 2$, and letting $x\to+\infty$ we get $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) = f(1) - 2$.

Observe that $g$ maps $[1,+\infty)$ to $\left[\frac12, 1\right)$ and that it maps each interval $\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$ to the interval $\left[\frac1{n+2},\frac1{n+1}\right]$.
Notice that $g$ is a monotonically increasing bijection, so in each case these mappings are themselves monotonically increasing bijections.

Define $f$ continuously on $[1,+\infty)$ however you wish (not necessarily monotonically), except that we require that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ exists and equals $f(1) - 2$.
With the relationship $f(g(x)) = f(x) +2$, one mapping of $g$ propagates the values of $f$ to $\left[\frac12, 1\right)$ and the limit condition ensures continuity at $x=1$.
Another mapping of $g$ propagates the values of $f$ to $\left[\frac13, \frac12\right]$, and in this manner we define $f$ inductively on all of $(0,+\infty)$.

---

To see that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$, pick any $x>0$.
We have

\begin{align}
f(x) &= f\Big(g(x)\Big) - 2
\\&= f\Big(g^2(x)\Big) - 4
\\&= f\Big(g^3(x)\Big) - 6
\\&=\,\,\dots
\\&= f\Big(g^k(x)\Big) - 2k
\end{align}

for all $k\geqslant 0$.
Equivalently,

$$f\Big(g^k(x)\Big) = f(x) + 2k$$

and letting $k\to\infty$ the LHS is $\lim_{z\to 0^+}f(z)$ while the RHS is $+\infty$.

Comment: I have some problem with the last line $k\to \infty$ then LHS is lim_{z\to 0+}f(z) while RHS is infinity.

Comment: What problem do you have with it?

Comment: you must first show that $lim_{z\to 0+}f(z)$ exists then only$ lim_{k\to \infty}f(g^k(x)=lim_{x\to 0+}f(z)$.

Comment: please use the definition of limit to show that the limit is infinity.

Comment: You can make it rigorous as follows. Let $x_0$ be such that $f(x_0) =\min_{x\in\left[\frac12,1\right]}f(x)$. Notice that the minimum exists and is attained because $f$ is continuous and $\left[\frac12,1\right]$ is compact. Then $\min_{x\in\left[\frac13,\frac 12\right]}f(x) = f(x_0) + 2$. Similarly, $\min_{x\in\left[\frac14,\frac 13\right]}f(x) = f(x_0) + 4$. You can proceed inductively.